# THREE.js problems with importing GLTFLoaders

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two problems with three.js on my WordPress page.

First:
I cannot import GLTFLoader. The error message says: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "THREE/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." However while I put "/" it tries to import from my server and if I put "//" it's looking for https://three/examples/. Which is also not working.

Here You can see part of my code:

```
<script type="module">
// Find the latest version by visiting https://cdn.skypack.dev/three.
 import * as THREE from '//cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0';
 import {GLTFLoader} from 'THREE/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
</script>

<script>
 //load 3d model
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'https://www.historia3d.pl/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/mini_3D02.glb', function ( gltf ) {
        model = gltf.scene.children[0];
        model.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
    undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    } );
</script>
```

Second: I want to use OrbitControls. But I want to check mouse position only while the coursor hover over canvas.

The code:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);
```

Comment: were you able to load three.module.js localy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> import * as THREE from '//cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0';
> import {GLTFLoader} from 'THREE/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

It is not recommended to import modules from different locations. Do it like so for now:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

You also have to put your code into the same script tag. Keep in mind that you are not importing global scripts but ES6 modules (which have a module scope). It should be:

```js
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';


 //load 3d model
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'https://www.historia3d.pl/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/mini_3D02.glb', function ( gltf ) {
        model = gltf.scene.children[0];
        model.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
    undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    } );
</script>
```

> I want to use OrbitControls. But I want to check mouse position only while the cursor hover over canvas.

It seems you are not creating `OrbitContorls` correctly. The second parameter is mandatory and missing right now. Try it with:

```js
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);
```

`renderer.domElement` represents your canvas.

Comment: Thank You for helping. Unfortunatlly now all my Canvas went to be black and I cannpt figure out what I am doing wrong
EDIT: sorry I am stupid. By mistake I deleted one line where I was defining nessesery variables

Comment: Be sure to add some lights to your scene. Use one of the official examples as a code template e.g. https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_horse.