# Accesing three.js library

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use three.js library to load my 3D model into website, but when I tried to do so (downloaded three package as zip file) I got an error. I have 3D_Site directory on Desktop and in there I keep all site files such as index.html and script.js. Beside of that there is unzipped directory named three. My script.js file looks that way:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from '../3D_Site/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( 'Spartan.fbx', function ( gltf ) {
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

All like in the example in documentation. Import path is relative to current directory, I also tried to do it in this way

But when I load the webpage I got an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Error solving module specifier "three.js". Relative module specifiers must start with "./", "../", or "/".

All is good with library itself. But in that library is use of another JS files and the problem is with them. How should I move my files? Or maybe I downloaded wrong files? Please tell me how to run three.js on website. I appreciate any answer.

Before you write me that there is [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883095/three-js-problems-with-importing-gltfloaders), I read it already and nothing detailed there helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an import map to your `index.html` so it's possible for your app to resolve the `three` bare import specifier. Try it with:

```html
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "../3D_Site/three/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

`script.js` should be an ES6 module and import `three.js` like so:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

Comment: So what do I have to do is add that import map into the head section in index.html and add `import * as THREE from 'three';` on top os script.js file, right? And in index.html use of index.html should looks like this `<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>`?

Comment: Correct. Have you given it a try?

Comment: Yes, I have given it a try but it didn't work