# How to load a glb file in three.js

Tags: three.js

My goal is to run a website locally with the back-written in flask and the front end with three.js, everything works fine because i do not see any errors in the console (devtools) but for some reason it is not showing the model, I have the camera, scene and render, I also loaded the model and added to the scene

```html
<body>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"  >
        import * as THREE from 'three';
        let scene, camera, renderer, stats, model;
        const loader;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.Width / window.Height, 0.1, 1000);
        
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.Width, window.Height);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.load( "{{ url_for('static', filename='free_1975_porsche_911_930_turbo.glb') }}", 
        function ( gltf ) {
            scene.add( gltf.scene );
            gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
            gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
            gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
            gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
            gltf.asset;
        },
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },
        function ( error ) {
            console.error( error );
        } 
        );
        function animate()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
```

why isn't this code showing the model in the browser

the model from [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/free-1975-porsche-911-930-turbo-8568d9d14a994b9cae59499f0dbed21e)

Comment: `GLTFLoader` is not imported! see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67884400), moreover, you are defining the loader as `const`, then you assign the value to it!